# MySQL matching many columns into one with left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables like this one

```
name  | fNatId | mNatId
=======================
Smith |      1 |      1
Doe   |      1 |      0
Owen  |      0 |      2
```

and this one

```
id | countryName
================
 0 | U.S.
 1 | U.K.
 2 | Canada
```

And I want to translate the first table into this

```
Name    | Father's Nationality | Mother's Nationality
=====================================================
Smith   | U.K.                 | U.K.
Doe     | U.K.                 | U.S.
Owen    | U.S.                 | Canada
```

How do I do this? Using two `LEFT JOIN`'s throws `Not unique table/alias` error. Using only one would match both the columns into either father's or mother's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use unique alias name for your table.  Considering your first table as `users` and second table as `countries`, did you try this way ? Following should work exactly as you're looking for.

```
SELECT u.name as Name, c1.countryName as FathersNationality, c2.countryName as MothersNationality

FROM users as u

LEFT JOIN countries as c1 ON c1.id = u.fNatId

LEFT JOIN countries as c2 ON c2.id = u.mNatId
```